# Re-Add Me Menu to Ubuntu Lucid

Tags: ubuntu

I removed the MeMenu from the top bar in Ubuntu.  I was thinking it would only remove the shutdown button, but it appears they are bundled together as one widget.  Anyway, anyone know how to get this back on the menu.. I don't see it in the "Add to Panel.." list.

Answer (score 3):

It's called the "indicator applet session", you need to have the "indicator-me" package installed.

Answer (score 1):

Some how I lost the "Hibernate" option in the power down icon in Ubuntu 10.04.
Just re-installing package "Indicator Applet session" did not restore "Hibernate".

Here is the solution which restored that item to the drop down list.

Using Synaptic Package Manager, I found the following
three packages which I re-installed.

"indicator-me"
"indicator-messages"
"indicator-applet"

Having these re-installed, I then re-installed
"indicator applet session"

rebooted the computer and did a login and the
"Hibernate" option was now in the drop down menu list.